# DOM: fetch all text nodes in the document (PHP)

Tags: php, dom, text, traversal

I've have the following (PHP) code that traverses an entire DOM document to get all of the text nodes. It's a bit of a ugly solution, and I'm sure there must be a better way... so, is there?

```
$skip = false;
$node = $document;
$nodes = array();
while ($node) {
    if ($node->nodeType == 3) {
        $nodes[] = $node;
    }
    if (!$skip && $node->firstChild) {
        $node = $node->firstChild;
    } elseif ($node->nextSibling) {
        $node = $node->nextSibling;
        $skip = false;
    } else {
        $node = $node->parentNode;
        $skip = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The XPath expression you need is `//text()`. Try using it with [`DOMXPath::query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php). For example:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$textnodes = $xpath->query('//text()');
```