# How to strip out all html tags ? can we save it separately?

Tags: php, regex, tags, html-parsing, preg-match

I would like to get rid of any html tag within a text in order to translate it sentence by sentence.

I try to use preg_match to return an array of the different sentences without success ..
witout luck.

Is it possible to store the tags somewhere to reinsert it later on in the code ? once the text is translated ?

For now I have :

```
public function translate($text) {

    $bool = preg_match('/(<[^>]+)/i', $text, $strings_to_translate); //untested
    // Ruan Regex /(<p(>|\s+[^>]*>).*?<\/p>)/i
    //Ideally strip dupes from this before looping

    var_dump($strings_to_translate);

    foreach($strings_to_translate as $to_translate) {

        echo $to_translate;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use regexes to parse HTML. Consider using [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) instead, which will parse your content into a proper DOM structure.

Comment: You want to use a DOM parser, [fetch all the text nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768737/dom-fetch-all-text-nodes-in-the-document-php), translate those and [write them back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783). Or, if you want to translate sentence by sentence (e.g. no risk of breaking html elements), use `strip_tags` and then `str_replace` the sentences in the original html.

Comment: I am working on it, could you give a example of how to reinsert the translated text into the DOM please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `split("\n", strip_tags($text))` to get an array of the data by line (or replace `"\n"` with `"."` to get sentences.

Comment: but how do you get the translated text back into the stripped tags then?

Comment: what does the ==> ' <== stand for in "'\n" ?

Comment: typo - removed the `'`